# JTAG Debug Design for a processor

Tags: microprocessor, jtag

My professor is designing a processor based on OpenRisc. He has told me to set up a JTAG Debug environment in his processor. Now, he gave me some documents which contain TAP controller, Advanced Debug Interface, AXI module and a CPU core interconnected to each other. I did my research on the internet. I learnt that TAP controller is usually on a chip which gets interfaced to TDI and TDO pins of the processor. Could someone explain me what is the internal debug unit in the processor?

Comment: You expect us to mindread what your professor wants?

Comment: no. actually i am trying to understand what he meant by saying he wants a similar environment in his processor. I want to know when someone designs a processor, is it the debug unit on the processor which he designs or the external jtag interface that he designs? @PlasmaHH

Comment: Those are questions for your professor.

Answer (score 2):

The JTAG interface is standardized, so there isn't much left to design. You need to implement the standard state machine that handles `TMS`, and handling for the various shift registers that can be connected to `TDI` and `TDO`.

Implementing a debug circuit generally involves accepting data that is shifted in through `TDI`, usually there is one register of fixed length, the `IR`, and one or more registers of varying length that can be connected to the `DR` path.

Generally, you want to implement at least the following commands in the `IR`:

- `BYPASS` (all ones): Connect a one bit register with no function during `DR`.
- `BOUNDARY_SCAN` (typically, all zeroes): Connect a register containing one bit for each I/O pin on the package to `DR`, load the current state during `CAPTURE-DR`, and write the new state during `UPDATE-DR`.

For processors with more intelligent debugging capabilities, you also want a third mode where the debug interface is connected to `DR`, and ideally a fourth mode where you can read out an ID code to identify the chip. You can also use additional `IR` values if that is helpful, but for a simple design I'd start with

- `BOUNDARY_SCAN` (0b00)
- `IDCODE` (0b01)
- `DEBUG` (0b10)
- `BYPASS` (0b11)

Preload the `IR` with the `IDCODE` instruction during `CAPTURE-IR`, that will make scanning the bus easier (for that to work, `IDCODE` needs to be all zero except for the LSB -- look at the [ARM implementation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0413c/Babeagge.html) for an example).

The `DR` for the `DEBUG` command is what you need to design. You have full freedom to build any mapping there that you want, and the ideal mapping depends on your processor architecture. Your debug interface can ignore the shifting, and just implement a synchronous parallel data bus -- every time you enter `CAPTURE-DR` state while the `IR` is `DEBUG`, a word is transferred from the outgoing FIFO, and every time you enter `UPDATE-DR` in `DEBUG` mode, a word is transferred to the incoming FIFO.

Generally, you want at least the following functionality:

- Define code breakpoints
- Define data breakpoints
- Define breakpoint instructions (so you get infinite breakpoints by replacing instructions)
- Read and alter CPU state
- Copy register values to the debugger
- Copy data from the debugger to registers
- Copy memory data to debugger
- Copy data from the debugger to memory
- Execute arbitrary instructions
- Test whether the CPU is currently running
- Halt execution
- Execute single instructions from the current state
- Restart execution
- Override whether interrupts are enabled (this makes your life a lot easier when you have a periodic timer but you want to debug something else)

Some of these may overlap -- again, looking at the way it is implemented on ARM is perhaps not the worst idea:

- Writing memory can be achieved by writing to registers, then running a "store" instruction normally.
- Writing registers can be achieved by connecting the data bus to the boundary scan interface and issuing a "load" instruction
- Halting the CPU can be achieved by defining a breakpoint that will trigger on any instruction
- The breakpoint instruction can be defined with a data breakpoint that triggers on a specific value during a data transfer that is tagged as an instruction fetch

If you have a pipelined design where instructions may need to be completed before the machine state has settled, use the `RUN-TEST/IDLE` state for that: generate a clock impulse everytime you pass through there, and have a way to find out from the `DR` in `DEBUG` mode whether the pipeline is empty. It is completely acceptable to require a debugger to pass through `RUN-TEST/IDLE` four times after giving a command to stop execution, that just becomes part of the interface.

In general it is preferable to keep the on-chip implementation as simple as possible, and handle all the complexity on the host side, for example, the ARM increments the `PC` with every instruction it executes, so the debug driver needs to keep track of how many instructions it issued, and correct the `PC` before restarting.